# Create a table from a list of strings in python (.fastq files path mapping)

Tags: python, pandas, fastq

I have created a 'kind of' table from a list of file paths and filenames, but I think that the way I did was not the best. I would like to ask you how my code should be, and also how I could actually create a dataframe with headers linking this code to pandas.

My code:

```
import os
current_dir = os.getcwd()
files_in_dir = os.listdir(current_dir)
for file_name in files_in_dir:
    file_path = os.path.join(current_dir, file_name)
    if "R1" in file_path:
        sample = file_name.split('_')[0]
        file_path2 = file_path.replace("R1", "R2")
        print(sample + '\t' + file_path + '\t' + file_path2)
```

**output** (not a proper table):

```
AG16      /home/user/folder1/AG16_R1.fastq    /home/user/folder1/AG16_R2.fastq<p>
AG13      /home/user/folder1/AG13_R1.fastq    /home/user/folder1/AG13_R2.fastq<p>
AG2       /home/user/folder1/AG2_R1.fastq     /home/user/folder1/AG2_R2.fastq<p>
...<p>
```

What I would like to add:

code above plus:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
data = [sample, file_path, file_path2]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['sample', 'r1', 'r2'])
print(df)
```

**Thank you very much!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

current_dir = os.getcwd()
files_in_dir = os.listdir(current_dir)

data = []

for file_name in files_in_dir:
    file_path = os.path.join(current_dir, file_name)
    if "R1" in file_path:
        sample = file_name.split('_')[0]
        file_path2 = file_path.replace("R1", "R2")
        data.append([sample, file_path, file_path2])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['sample', 'r1', 'r2'])
print(df)
```

Comment: That's great, thank you! May I ask you something else? At ```file_path2 = file_path.replace("R1", "R2")``` I'd like to explicitly ask for R2, as the if condition to R1, as well as ask for other matches like 'stats' within the file names. I've trying something like this: ```if "R1" in file_path:
        sample = file_name.split('-')[0]
    elif "R2" in file_path:
        file_path2 = file_path
    elif "STATS" in file_path:
        stats = file_path
        data.append([sample, file_path, file_path2, stats])```

Comment: You can try:  if "R1" in file_path:
        sample = file_name.split('_')[0]
        file_path2 = file_path.replace("R1", "R2")
        data.append([sample, file_path, file_path2, None])
    elif "R2" in file_path:
        sample = file_name.split('_')[0]
        file_path2 = file_path
        data.append([sample, file_path, file_path2, None])
    elif "STATS" in file_path:
        sample = file_name.split('_')[0]
        stats = file_path
        data.append([sample, None, None, stats])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['sample', 'r1', 'r2', 'stats'])
print(df)